# Updating POD in my xcode app fail (ruby / rbenv error)

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, cocoapods, rbenv

I've never been able to update pods in my app as it always have failed, but I'm currently obligated to upgrade a lot of things, so I need to get my hands into it.

My goal is to set my app back to newest version of **Deployment Target**, and install latest version of pods (**Firebase/Core**, **Firebase/AdMob** & **Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK**).

So I deleted the following things:

- "Pods" folder
- "Podfile.lock" file

Now any command starting with **pod** fails with the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    20: from /Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    19: from /Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    18: from /Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
    17: from /Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    16: from /Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    15: from /Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods.rb:75:in `<module:Pod>'
    13: from /Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    12: from /Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    11: from /Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/core_overrides.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
     9: from /Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
     8: from /Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.1/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
     6: from /Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
     5: from /Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/typhoeus-1.3.1/lib/typhoeus.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
     3: from /Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
     2: from /Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/digest/sha2.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': dlopen(/Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin16/digest/sha2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin16/digest/sha2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/antoinenedelec/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/2.5.0/x86_64-darwin16/digest/sha2.bundle
```

I tried installing new version of ruby, change version of ruby on rbenv, but I have no idea if I'm doing this well, or why ruby is used there..

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an upgrade broke your Ruby which depended on a version of OpenSSL that got cleaned up.

When this happens the easiest solution is to uninstall and reinstall (rebuild) the version of Ruby you need. It's usually best to bump to the latest version of that particular series, like in this case 2.5.8.

You can see which versions are supported with:

```sh
ruby-build --definitions | grep ^2.5
```

So try:

```sh
rbenv uninstall 2.5.0
rbenv install 2.5.8
rbenv global 2.5.8
```